# Spring Framework HttpSessionRequiredException

Tags: session-timeout, spring-3, httpsession

We are using Spring Framework in our project. If application gets timeout, it gives below error. How can I redirect to login page when it gives this error? Can I configure application-context for this error?

PS.: We don't use Spring-Security

```
 org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException : Expected session
    attribute 'UserPrinciple'
          at
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:103)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:614)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
          at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
          at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
          at
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
          at
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
          at
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
          at
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol
    $AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint
    $SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
          at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    $Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/login.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this answer?

Comment: Add above code in your web.xml, When HttpSessionRequiredException exception occurs you will be redirected to login page.